# How do I resolve connection issues between two 10/100Base-Tx to 100Base-Fx fast Ethernet converters

Tags: networking

[image]
My network at two points, A and B, have the same connection devices that have been working well until recently. A (A is the internet entry point) transmits internet to B (B is the data centre) and B distributes to other locations, ie. C, D, F,G. A and B are connected by fiber using an OLT.

I never noticed before, but since it stopped working, I only see three lights under TX blinking at both point A and B.

Obviously the two devices are not communicating, but does it mean one of them is broken?

Comment: Hi Masssly and welcome.  How long are the fibres between A and B?  My first guess would be damage to those, before suspecting the devices. What is the manufacturer and model?

Comment: Having dealt with more than 3000 fiber converters, i can surely write, that it is common for converters to stop working suddenly.

Comment: I suspect your environment is better regulated than most of mine, which are usually temporary sites, where things tend to break because of feet, tools, and similar -- which means it's basically always a cable of one kind or another.  3000 is a lot of experience, do you know what part of them tends to fail?

Comment: @jonathanjo 100BASE-FX only uses LEDs which can last for ever - but they can break, too. Burned-out receivers should be very rare due to the low power involved.

Comment: Well, the most errors i've seen was after thunder storms. But i have tried to turn off and turn on a converter at least 20 times, where it did not work afterwards. 3000 is also over a span of around 12 years.

Comment: @jonathanjo Distance between blocks A and B is about 100 Meters. The fibre cable is buried underground. It's thick black like [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Optical_fiber_cable.jpg this]. I'm not sure though what name it is but I can take a picture tomorrow and show you. Are you asking for the *manufacturer and model* for the Converter devices or the Fibre cable?

Comment: @Cown If one stops working, should the other be affected. Am I right to think that, the FX Leds not being on means that the device isn't working properly?It's hard to think that both would stop working at same time. Currently, both only have their TX LEDs on. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: @jonathanjo The cables in my environment are buried so I would rule out feet, but tools, not so confidently because a lot of weeding takes place frequently.

Comment: @Zac67 My receivers have been working for about 3 years now. Is that a long time enough to expect a burnout?

Comment: Decent converters can run for 10++ years but you never know...

Comment: @jonathanjo The cables in my environment are buried so I would rule out feet, but tools, not so confidently because a lot of weeding takes place frequently

Comment: @Cown I couldn't rule off thunderstorms too.

Comment: @Cown thunderstorms, thanks for info. In some parts of Spain I'm familiar with it's still common for people to unplug all their televisions, computers, and most especially modems during thunderstorms.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

As it seems, the fiber link is down. There is no link light for 100BASE-FX on either side as you wrote. Note that usually, both sides' link lights go dark when one of the converters dies or one of the fibers fail.

Possible causes:

1) One of the converters died.

Check out with a spare converter or any other device speaking 100BASE-FX. For a quick test, disconnect the 100BASE-TX side from the network (unless you've got STP active) and use an SC-SC patch cable to connect a converter to itself, it should link with itself. (Some converters require that the 100BASE-TX is linked though.) Looking at the transmitter side even through a digicam is useless due to -FX's long 1300 nm wavelength.

2) The fiber is broken

If a spare/test device links on both converters but not across the fiber, the latter is disrupted. Check the patch cables for damage or tight bends - single-mode is especially sensitive to an undercut bend radius.

Generally, it's a good idea to use pluggable transceivers in managed switches. If you use SFP transceivers with DOM (digital optical monitoring) in a managed switch you can monitor the transmitted and received power on the link.

While you're at it you might want to go for 1000BASE-LX (it looks like you've got single-mode fiber). You might also want to go for 1000BASE-BX and run two links aggregated with failover capability - there are many very affordable 3rd-party transceivers around. -BX is also a solution when one fiber has failed but can't be replaced and the other still works.

Comment: Option 1 tried, and as shown below, TR and FX are lit up. https://i.imgur.com/8M244hl.jpg Any advice on how to check if the fibre is broken?

Comment: The crude test is to shine a bright flashlight (or a simple fiber tester) into one end - with just 100 m you should be able to see something. A more real test is to run another fiber in parallel and use it as loopback or as 2nd link fiber. Or use bidi transceivers with each fiber alternately.